# PyTorch Faster R-CNN ResNet50 - support for occlusion?

Tags: pytorch, object-detection

Currently I'm using the PyTorch model Faster R-CNN ResNet50.  I instantiate this as follows:

```
model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
```

Then I more or less perform standard object detection, similar to this example on the PyTorch site:

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torchvision_tutorial.html

I'm getting great results with this model so far.  However, many annotation programs now support marking bounding boxes as "occluded".  I'm not sure if I can make this model take advantage of or incorporate this into it's training/calculations, can anybody provide a code example or link to an example that demonstrates this?  Can this model be used to take advantage of the "occlusion" tag in most annotation programs today?  Or do I need to choose a different model more specific to this purpose?